# Selection_sort (python)

Tags: python, selection-sort

I came across this code on selection sort algorithm:

```
ls = [2, 5, 1, -9, 10, 13, 7, 2]


def selection_sort(ls):
      for i in range(len(ls)):
         imin = min(range(i,len(ls)), key = lambda x: ls[x])
         ls[i], ls[imin] = ls[imin], ls[i]
```

I know the typical selection_sort with the if block, but this one is hard to understand. I tried to print `imin` with all possible i's and the result was 33337777 which doesn't make sense to me. I think my problem is that I don't know how this specific key works. Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: How can one understand a particular value during execution w/o knowing what the *input* to the function was?

Comment: Can you explain what you *do* understand about this code?

Comment: @khelwood thank you for the edit, im new to stack overflow, i really dont know how to construct everything in the right way.

Comment: @KellyBundy no im sorry, i tried for i in range(len(ls)):
    imin = min( range(i,len(ls)), key= lambda x: ls[x])
    print(imin) ,  to make the problem simpler and try to understand the code.

Comment: @KellyBundy "are we supposed to believe" man, why such an irony for someone who literally codes for 1 week? If you cant be patient with my bad format of the question, you dont have to answer

Comment: @KellyBundy i took the feedback buddy, and I was trying to fix the question but khelwood helped me and did it first , and I thank him for that. I dont know your age, your experiences or your background in life, but constructed criticism is something that you develop, irony, elitism and degration of someone when he is geniuenly trying to learn something new is something that I DO NOT accept, get it? so if you have nothing constructing  to add in a polite manner , then respectfully don't interfere at all.

Comment: @KellyBundy feel free to tell me then what I need to fix in a humaine manner and not like in a sarcastic and elitistic way. Believe I'm here to learn and I'll listen to your advice. Thank you.

Comment: Like I said, the number 33337777 is not the output for that input. Actual output is *eight* numbers, and they're 3, 2, 3, 7, 7, 6, 7 and 7.

Comment: @KellyBundy then probably i typed something wrong,  I will check it again, it didnt make sense to me also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**function declaration**

The statement is the function definition, Which takes one argument i.e. `list`

```
def selection_sort(ls):
```

**Loop Initialization**

A `for-loop` is defined that will iterate the list from `i = 0 to the len(ls)`.

```
for i in range(len(ls)):
```

### Main Logic

Inside the `for-loop`, there are 2 statements

```
imin = min(range(i,len(ls)), key = lambda x: ls[x])
```

The above code uses python's min function taking 2 arguments, an iterator and a function to find the minimum value from the list starting from index `i` to `len(ls)` and return the item's index using the lambda function passed as the second argument.

```
ls[i], ls[imin] = ls[imin], ls[i]
```

The above code is responsible for swapping the minimum item with the item at the index i of the list.

Comment: thank you for the great answer ill read it and try to understand where my problem was. Thank you also for not paying attention to my bad format and you werent ironic or elitist towards me.

Comment: So  all in all imin returns ls[x] , that's what lambda x: ls[x] does right? I think i get it now! thank you @Sidharth Mudgil

Comment: of course it did